# GCP : Dynamic configuration management (Application level Configurations)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-zookeeper, configuration-management

Is there any ***dynamic*** **configuration service** in GCP ecosystem which the apps can integrate with, and get the capability to reflect any configuration changes at runtime. (i.e the config service pushes the changes to the application layer as soon as any change is made).

In the past, have seen a similar solution (built on top of apache zookeeper), thus want to explore if something similar exists within GCP as a service.

PS : Bounded eventual consistency of configurations across all app boxes is a must (max delay 5 seconds).

Comment: No, there isn't a dedicated service for that. You can store your key value data in env variable in your services, or use Firestore or secret manager for that

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere isn't this exactly what [runtime-configurator](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator) does?

Comment: Much more simple answer: do not use Deployment Manager! The latest entry in the release is in 2020! And the latest entry that mention the runtime configurator is in 2017. Forget it, definitively!

Comment: does this help: https://www.watsh.io ?